# Using Wordpress login for a non word-press website

Tags: login, authentication

If I have a website on Wordpress say A, now I am making another website  using React, say B (non-wordpress)

We would have most of the users who are already on A, and some new ones, who might come directly on B.
We do not want to have different login/signup mechanism for both.

Hence the need is to see if we could reuse Wordpress (existing) authentication at both places?
If yes, how? Since Wordpress authentication is in Php, can it be used/invoked from javascript?

Any pointers would be of great help.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes but there is a premise of what kind of websites are you going to authenticate. Different websites come with different authentication method such as forums and so on. There is no one 1 bullet proof solution for all. You need to specify rather than openly discussing a vague and generic topic.

Comment: The new web app will be on Javascript(using React) and is intended for some custom features. We would have most of the users who are already on A, and some new ones, who might come directly on B.
We do not want to have different login/signup mechanism for both.
Hence the need to see if we could reuse Wordpress (existing) authentication at both places?

Comment: You may refer to this [Handbook - Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) for examples and explanation.

Comment: Forget to mention, since you said that it is an app, so refer to the handbook for the rest api which should help you.